# How to put a title in my Navbar with Xcode and Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I'm developing an app so I need a UINavigationBar. I want to put a title inside of it so I placed a UILabel with the title I want to show. When I run the simulator, it shows everything okay except the title: it doesn't appear. I used constraints to place the UILabel so I guess it's not hidden everywhere. In my Storyboard everything shows fine.

Comment: navigationBar.topItem.title = "some title"

Answer (score 2):

If you're having a navigation controller with your view controller, then you cans et the title using

```
self.title = @"YOUR_TITLE";
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried on a device? Does it still do the same?

Try Adding it directly to the nav bar.  Double click the `UINavigationBar` and add your title

or

Double click `UINavigationBar` and add it in the `Title` section that appears in the attributes inspector

Or in code  [putting labels, buttons on the navigation bar iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611147/putting-labels-buttons-on-the-navigation-bar-ios)

Comment: So I can't use a UILabel?

Comment: You can if you want to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611147/putting-labels-buttons-on-the-navigation-bar-ios

Comment: You can, you just shouldn't unless there's a really good reason.  See Henit's answer for the preferred way of displaying a title in the navigation bar.

Comment: Why would Henits answer be preferred over adding it in interface builder?