# mulpitle UILabel in Navigation titleView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Normally, I'm used to create single UILabel in self.navigationItem.titleView. But now my client want to add multiple UILabel in self.navigationItem.titleView. I'm not sure whether it would be feasible to implement or not as follow. If feasible, please let me how to do it.

[image]

Comment: add customview in  self.navigationItem.titleView

Comment: have u checked this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17611568/5362916

Comment: @bhargavbajani I've already done but it does not work.